# Span text start from bottom and as its a new line is added. the span is pushed up by one line

Tags: html, css

I want the span to start from top and as text length increases fill more lines but it starts from bottom to top.
![ image for the problem] : https://ibb.co/KXFtC2g

```
<div style="width:70%;margin-left: 15%">

    <section name="about">
        <h2>عن الكورال</h2>
        <article >
            <div style="height: 100%;">
            <span>
                hey.
                Well this is a vety professional discription of our team.
                feel free to check these xyz.
            </span>
            </div>
        </article>
        <figure >
            <img src="assets/team.jpg" >
        </figure>
    </section>
</div>

article {
       display:inline-block;
       width:40%;
       }

figure{
     display:inline-block;
     width:40%;
     }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should achieve what you're looking for.

```
figure{
     display:inline-block;
     width:40%;
     float: right
     }
```

See a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gamyob2k/)

Comment: thanks, It worked. 
I will be more thankful if you tell why float right helped ?

Comment: @PhilopateerNabil don't use float. add `vertical-align:top` (see the duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks worked and now that makes sense